# How to send data through url params in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I would like to know how to add url params in wso2 for a url similar to http://localhost/mytestapi/123456 where 123456 is the id I want to pass onto the mytestapi api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the API and Endpoint like below. I gave a sample API with Endpoint mapping. For more information, please check on this documentation on [Map the Parameters of your Backend URLs with the API Publisher URLs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Map+the+Parameters+of+your+Backend+URLs+with+the+API+Publisher+URLs)

[image]